# pecl install memcached - Can't find ZLIB headers under "/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"

Tags: php, memcached, zlib, pecl, php-memcached

I have installed PHP, zlib and memcached using Homebrew on a Mac with Apple silicon. I am trying to install the memcached extension for PHP using

```
sudo pecl install memcached
```

When it prompts me for `zlib directory [no] :` I specified `"/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"`

I have confirmed that this directory contains the files zlib.h and zconf.h. `brew info zlib` also tells me

```
For compilers to find zlib you may need to set:
  export LDFLAGS="-L/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib"
  export CPPFLAGS="-I/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"

For pkg-config to find zlib you may need to set:
  export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"
```

So I seem to be supplying the correct path for zlib. However, running `sudo pecl install memcached` is throwing the following error:

```
checking whether to use system FastLZ library... no
checking for ZLIB... yes, shared
checking for pkg-config... /opt/homebrew/bin/pkg-config
configure: error: Can't find ZLIB headers under "/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include"
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/temp/memcached/configure --with-php-config=/opt/homebrew/opt/php/bin/php-config --with-libmemcached-dir=no --with-zlib-dir=/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include --with-system-fastlz=no --enable-memcached-igbinary=no --enable-memcached-msgpack=no --enable-memcached-json=no --enable-memcached-protocol=no --enable-memcached-sasl=no --enable-memcached-session=no' failed
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: I have already tried brew reinstall zlib, and export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/lib/pkgconfig"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue and managed to get it working on Mac using the path:

```
/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib
```

NOT "/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib/include" even though that is technically the folder which contains the headers, the error message is misleading.

For me, the --with-zlib-dir= argument did nothing, I had to provide the path when prompted during installation:

```
pecl install memcached
zlib directory [no] : /opt/homebrew/opt/zlib
```

Comment: In my case I also had to `brew install libmemcached` and then specify `/opt/homebrew/opt/libmemcached` at the `libmemcached directory [no] :` prompt and then it finally worked. Thanks mate

Comment: Great! The same works also on Linux (in my case, Ubuntu). I had `zlib.h` installed in `/usr/include/`, but providing this dir to the `pecl install memcached` caused the error. I had to use `/usr` instead (also for `libmemcached` dir). Thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 1):

Could not find how to use the info in the other answers. The environment variables given in the question do not change the result, even when using the accepted answer.

The fix was the one give in ancient PHP issue https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=56522 :

```
PHP_ZLIB_DIR=/opt/homebrew/opt/zlib pecl install memcache
```